# VS C# Button with Mailto function - it needs to open Outlook's new mail window

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook

**What I am trying to do:**

A user clicks a button on a ASP.net page and it opens a Outlook 'new mail' window.
That's all.

**My Problem:**

With this -->

```
     using Outlook = Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


    OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();
    MailItem mailItem = (MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

    mailItem.Subject = "Test";
    mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>This is the message body</body></html>";

    mailItem.Display(false);
```

And several other code I've tried, I am getting security errors on my IIS web server - Access is denied. But on localhost Outlook opens fine.

I looked all over, and everyone suggests that NETWORKSERVICE should be the user that has full security rights. Did that. And after reading a bit more, People are suggesting to not try and open Outlook over a web server for several reasons. So I decided to leave Interops.Outlook.

Then I also tried the following, which again works on my localhost, but when published to the web server does not respond when the button is clicked. It literally does nothing.

```
    string subject = "Test subject";
    string emailTag = string.Format("mailto:someone@test.com?subject={0}", subject);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(emailTag);
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `<a href='mailto:mailto:someone@test.com?subject={0}'>Email</a>` ? This is how it should be done for websites. Launching a process in IIS would launch it on server not on client.

Comment: Don't use `Microsoft.Office.Interop`. And if you should get it to work it is the server that is going to open Outlook. Not the client.

Comment: You're (trying to) open Outlook on the *server*, not on the *machine where the browser is*. You have to get the *browser* to do the job for you - not launch new processes, not automate Outlook.

Comment: @vendettamit I did this. it works. I just want to use a button as opposed to a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hyperlink to open the default email client from website.

`<a class='button' href='mailto:mailto:someone@test.com?subject={0}'>Email</a>`

To display a hyperlink as button you can CSS like below:

```css
.button {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<a class='button' href='mailto:mailto:someone@test.com?subject={0}'>Email</a>
```

If you are using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) then it would be more easy. simply apply role attribute to show link as button:

```
<a role='button' href='mailto:mailto:someone@test.com?subject={0}'>Email</a>
```

Comment: Okay this will do the job. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As [vendettamit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881798/vendettamit) said you can use SenEmail to open Outlook or another default mail application on client side. [Here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/mailto.htm) you can find all stuff that ca be used within `mailto:`

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I did <a href='mailto:mailto:someone@test.com?subject={0}'>Email</a> do this. It's just that I want to make use of a button instead of a link. But I see I'll have to continue with a link then.

Comment: with css you can make your link look like button.
``

Answer (score -2):

so I initially wanted to code inside an ASP button. And the following code to do that is :

```
               ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FormLoading", "window.open('mailto:someone@test.test', 'email');", true);
```

This opens my outlook without issues plus I can add additional methods to the button as well.

Comment: Your original question was different and the solution was provided based on that. Now you have unmarked the answer and trying to answer your question by changing scope of your question.